# How to use the service worker in dev mode with Create React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, service-worker

I am using `create-react-app` version 4 with `cra-template-pwa`.

From looking at the source code of [serviceWorkerRegistration.js](https://github.com/cra-template/pwa/blob/25cb9f06938c671507684a8438c347d3c8bc8b24/packages/cra-template-pwa/template/src/serviceWorkerRegistration.js#L22), it seems like the service worker is only registered in production because of that check:

```
export function register(config) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        // Logic to register the service worker can be found here.
    }
```

I would like to register the service worker in development mode too. I removed the `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` check and also another `isLocalhost` check.

The development build tries to load the service worker at `www.example.com/service-worker.js` just as I hoped. The problem is that the service worker file is not compiled to the `public` folder so `www.example.com/service-worker.js` returns a `404`.

Copying the file to the `public` folder manually  does not work either:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Is there a way to get the service worker to work in development mode?

Answer (score 5):

First add craco to the react project [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco)

then create custome craco plugin using below files

serviceWorkerRegistration.js

```
change this line ===>  if ("process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && serviceWorker" in navigator)

to ===>  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator)
```

craco.config.js

```
const cracoServiceWorkerConfig = require("./cracoServiceWorkerConfig");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [{ plugin: cracoServiceWorkerConfig }],
};
```

cracoServiceWorkerConfig.js

```
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require("workbox-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    overrideWebpackConfig: ({ webpackConfig, cracoConfig, pluginOptions, context: { env, paths } }) => {
        const isEnvDevelopment = env === "development";
        if (isEnvDevelopment) {
            const newConfig = {
                ...webpackConfig,
                plugins: [
                    ...webpackConfig.plugins,
                    isEnvDevelopment &&
                        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest({
                            swSrc: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/service-worker.js"),
                            dontCacheBustURLsMatching: /\.[0-9a-f]{8}\./,
                            exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/, /LICENSE/],
                            maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
                        }),
                ],
            };
            return newConfig;
        } else {
            return webpackConfig;
        }
        // Always return the config object.
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply cant. The CRA-service worker is an abstraction of the Javascript browser feature that is service-worker. It makes it possible to easily write this service worker, but it will only compile on the build.
You can always write your own service worker in JS and test it in dev. But you dont want to.

Comment: I will read some things and come back at you if I have any new info. I dont want to give any wrong info.

Comment: Usually during development you don't want the hassle with the PWA, but when devloping it of course you want to test it locally. I solved it by running `yarn build` and copying the `/build/service-worker.js` to the `/public` folder before running `yarn start`.  I need the setupProxy, so I can not just serve the build, but really need to run `yarn start`. You can automate this process with a script in your package.json, but you will miss out on the hot reload. I also use the incognito window to test, so I can start fresh each time instead of having to unregister the service worker manually.

Comment: @bas there's a solution that actually works with Hot Reload, it's very tricky though, it took me a few days to make.
Basically you have to create a separate webpack.config.json that will build the serviceWorker for you and put it in the build folder, this is helpful especially if the build process takes too long and you're working on serviceWorker. Then you would have a script, I personally use Gulp.js that watches for changes to the serviceWorker source code, and runs the webpack script everytime it's modified.
IN order to embed itwith the `yarn start` command, I embedded it command in Gulp